# How to get scale value using GreenSock Animation Platform (GSAP)

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm using GSAP's TweenMax to scale a div when a user clicks on a button.

However, what I want to do is be able to get the current scale value and/or know how to increment the scale value by say 0.5.

This is how I'm setting the scale when the button is click:
`TweenMax.to(mapContainer, 0.4, { scale: 1.3});`

So scaled to 1.3 over 0.4 seconds. So what I'm wanting to do is when a user clicks on that button again, it will scale it by an extra 0.5 each time.

Comment: I think you can use relative values by putting the value in quotes: scale:"10"

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in the GreenSock forums:

[Link to the question in the GreenSock Forums](http://forums.greensock.com/topic/9759-how-to-get-or-increment-the-scale-value/)

For anyone looking for a quick and accurate answer to any issue with GreenSock Animation Platform (GSAP), I'd encourage you to post your questions in GSAP's forums, is the best way to get the best and fastest answer possible. Nothing against StackOverflow, but GSAP forums are dedicated only to the engine.

Cheers,

Rodrigo.